# Using single CSS file for two static sites on AWS

Tags: css, amazon-s3

I have two single page sites that have identical designs and are each hosted on S3. I want to keep them separate, however, I want to maintain a single set of CSS files so I can keep the layouts identical but continue to improve the responsive layouts when necessary. I don't want to have to maintain two sets of files that are 98% identical.

I see that S3 allows one site to reference another site's files. So I could get that working. However, I'm at a loss for how to set that up locally for testing purposes. Am I looking to create a third "Shared" bucket that will hold dev and prod versions of the CSS files? That's going to require file modifications every time I want to push to prod. I feel like there's got to be an easier way.

Or do I just need to unify the files locally but upload the single set of css files to both sites? This still seems to require file modifications when running locally/pushing to prod.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *"I see that S3 allows one site to reference another site's files."* What are you referring to, here?

Comment: "However, I'm at a loss for how to set that up locally for testing purposes."